# Can someone ID this pcb for me? I got it from a salvaged keyboard

Tags: pcb, identification, keyboard

I salvaged a pcb from a keyboard and I need help finding a datasheet/pinout.  can someone help?[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you know the model number of the keyboard? Google that and "service manual". The odds of such a thing existing, though, are very low.

Comment: If you're trying to re-use it you're better off getting one of the open source USB keyboard controller projects.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't exist.   That's a proprietary PCB designed & manufacturers by (for?) the OEM equipment vendor.    That PCB is so cheap, they didn't even spring for a packaged IC.   See the little black blob?  THat's epoxy covering a bare silicon chip which they die-bonded to the PCB.   That's "toy grade" stuff, literally.